# How to tar gzip with the same folder name

Tags: shell, gzip, tar

All, I need to tar gzip the folder and the name should be same as the original folder name.

Example Directory : /user/abc/documents/20190101
I need to tar the 20190101 folder to 20190101.tar.gz by not explicitly specifying the name of the folder.

tar -czvf /user/abc/documents/20190101.tar.gz /user/abc/documents/20190101/testing/20190506-081500000

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell command to detect the directory name and capture it in a variable. Then use this variable to create the tar file.

For e.g.

**Create some files and directories:**

```
shell$ mkdir -p foo/001
shell$ mkdir -p foo/002
shell$ mkdir -p foo/003
shell$ touch foo/bar.txt
shell$ tree foo
foo
├── 001
├── 002
├── 003
└── bar.txt

3 directories, 1 file
shell$
```

**Check the directory structure**

```
shell$ cd foo
shell$ find . -type d
.
./001
./003
./002
shell$ find . -type d | grep -v "\.$"
./001
./003
./002
shell$
```

**Use find to detect the directories. Iterate in a loop and create tar files with same name as the directories.**

```
shell$ for x in `find . -type d | grep -v "\.$"`; do
> echo "Tarring $x..."
> tar cvzf $x.tar.gz $x
> done
Tarring ./001...
a ./001
Tarring ./003...
a ./003
Tarring ./002...
a ./002
shell$
```

**Verify**

```
shell$ tree .
.
├── 001
├── 001.tar.gz
├── 002
├── 002.tar.gz
├── 003
├── 003.tar.gz
└── bar.txt

3 directories, 4 files
shell$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you can use bash:

**targz.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(sed 's@\(.*/\)\([0-9]*\)/.*@\1|\2@' <<< "$1")
tar -czvf "${name%%|*}${name##*|}.tar.gz" "$1"
```

**Usage**

```
targz.sh "/user/abc/documents/20190101/testing/20190506-081500000"
```

**explanation**

```
sed '              # use sed
s@                 # substitute
\(.*/\)            # save first part into arg1 (\1)
\([0-9]*\)/        # save date into arg2 (\2)
.*@                # ignore all char to the end
\1|\2@' <<< "$1"   # print \1 | \2

${name%%|*}        # \1 --> path
${name##*|}        # \2 --> date
```